# Mongoose.js: is it possible to know if field was populated

Tags: mongoose

I have a document with objectId reference field that can be populated.

Is there a known way to know if the field was already populated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the `document.populated(path)` method ([as documented here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populated)). It returns the _id used for population, and `undefined` if the field has not been populated.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that it returns undefined if was not populated.